SignalR connection takes very long to connect in some cases
I have an asp net core backend and a wpf frontend
When i let run the backend on the localhost (on https) everything works fine and the SignalR connection is established very fast. But when I change the backend's ip to my local ip (i change it in the launchSettings.json) it takes very long to make this connection (the weird thing is that it always takes 120 seconds with only some milliseconds difference). Also normal API calls to my backend are still very fast and work as expected.
What is also is weird is that when I don't use my Middleware (i commented it out) then everything works as usual and the connection is fast again, but I don't have to do this when running on localhost! (middleware makes some DB accesses and uses a dbcontext but i added it scoped so it shouldnt be a problem?)
I also just found out that it runs perfectly fine over my local ip and http but wont with https
in my client i ignore the ssl certificate like this:

var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =  (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
    {
        try
        {
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            return false;
        }
    }
};

Here i add the MiddleWare:
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<KeyManagerDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    });
...
    builder.Services.AddScoped<DBLogger>();
...
    app.UseMiddleware<LoggerMiddleware>();

What's maybe also important to know is that i use my DBcontext both in my LoggerMiddleware and my Hub for SignalR, but i added it as scoped so it shouldn't be a Problem (and i don't get an error cause of that)
I also tried different ports
Temporary Fix:
in my LoggerMiddleware I use the httpcontext
The negotiating process of signalR doesn't like this at all
My temp fix is this if in my InvokeAsync in the Middleware:
    if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/keystream"))//keystream is the route of my hub
    {
         await _next(context);
         return;
    }


We can use the SignalR log to view the details of the connection, which can help understand at which step the delay occurs.

Are you negotiating? If so, does that take long?
